# How can I connect to a different database during application's runtime with Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

By default Laravel will connect into a database whose configurations showed in .env file. However, I want to have my application connected to a database which configurations will be provided by other internal service through HTTP (database host, username, password, ...).

So, how can I get my Laravel application connected into a database during runtime?

This thread: [Set database connection and language dynamically in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616869) gives me a nutshell approach on using middleware to connect to a database. But it does not explain on how I can connect to a database dynamically from any part of my Laravel codes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set database connection and language dynamically in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616869/set-database-connection-and-language-dynamically-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Config::set method to change your underlying config on the fly - to another database connection, assuming that is what you mean.

```
Config::set("database.connections.mysql", [
    "host" => "...",
    "database" => "...",
    "username" => "...",
    "password" => "...
]);
```