# How to change database name dynamically before authenticate in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have one application. in that, in login page along with username and password fields, there is another field company selection drop-down. like (comp1, comp2,comp3).
based on company selection I want to connect to that company related database.
all databases having the same tables. just I want to change database name and handle with that database throughout the app.

for that, I created on BeforeMiddleware. in that added the following code.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class BeforeMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $company_name = $_GET['company_name'];

        Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $company_name );
        DB::purge('mysql');
        DB::reconnect();

        if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName())
        {

            echo "Connected sucessfully to database ".DB::connection()->getDatabaseName().".";

        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

here the selected database is connected successfully but after i am getting 
`FatalErrorException Call to a member function prepare() on null` error.

please let me know how to change database name dynamically in single place

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I connect to a different database during application's runtime with Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51076972/how-can-i-connect-to-a-different-database-during-applications-runtime-with-lara)

Comment: I tried like the above mentioned link. still i am getting same error. FatalErrorException Call to a member function prepare() on null error.